# Write data to a file from a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, java-io

In Java...

I have data stored in a BufferedReader. (I got it as a response to an HTTP post request.)

How do I write this (binary) data to a file?

I know how to write Strings to files, but how do I take the data in the BufferedReader and put it into a file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What HTTP client library are you using to perform the HTTP POST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use a Reader to get bytes. Reader is used for reading character data, not binary data. Use the InputStream directly.

```
void write(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[512]; // optimize the size of buffer to your need
    int num;
    while ((num = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
      os.write(buf, 0, num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Output stream is clear - I can make an FileOutputStream for that. How do I turn my BufferedReader into a InputStream?

Comment: Why do you have to use a reader? Why can't you use InputStream directly to get the bytes?

Comment: @thehanseatic You don't turn your `BufferedReader` into an `InputStream`. You *start* with an `InputStream`. As you have binary data, using a `BufferedReader` is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up the confusion. I have gotten it to work using the method above.

Answer (score 1):

Start with [Basic I/O](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) then do the i, then the o, or if you want to conserve memory i/o, i/o i/o (rinse and repeat till no more i).